# ios - encoding a url string and sending it via NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest gives error

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection

I am trying to make a remote server call using this code:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender 
{    
    // Arguments are subject and body.
    NSString *urlString = @"my_url";

    NSString *email = self.email.text;
    NSString *password = self.password.text;


    NSString *url_to_send = [NSString stringWithFormat:urlString , email , password];;     

    NSString *escapedString = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                  (__bridge CFStringRef)url_to_send,
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    // Now send to the server    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // ***************
    // TODO: ok I dont really understand what this is
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    // **************

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {                  
         NSLog(@"This is data: %@" , data);
         NSLog(@"This is response: %@" , response);
         NSLog(@"This is error: %@" , error);

         if ( error == nil )
         {
             // Display a message to the screen.
         }
         else
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
         {
                 // Do something
         }
         else 
         {
             // Do something else                         
         }
     }];    
}
```

if i don't encode the URL, it actually comes back without an error. But if I encode the url, it gives this error:

```
This is data: (null)
2012-07-08 11:10:56.110 BusinessPlan[1630:14603] This is response: (null)
2012-07-08 11:10:56.111 BusinessPlan[1630:14603] This is error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x684a180 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=My_encoded_url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=my_encoded_url, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x6895d00 "unsupported URL"}
```

What does this error mean? Did I encode it incorrectly? Also, when I don't encode it, the data and response objects come back with values, but I wasn't sure how to get those values from those objects.  How do I tell what data is in those objectS?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you NSLog escapedString and check if it is a valid url ?

Comment: @MSK good point, i just tried to paste that url into the browser, but it gave a 400 bad request error.

Comment: Jason answered your problem. 1 uped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're encoding the entire string, which includes the scheme and the URI elements. You probably just want to encode the query part of your URL.

For example, if your URL were `http://www.example.com/whatever?u=jason&p=pass.!!`, you'd want to encode the query part but nothing else. The properly encoded URL for this example would look like:

`http://www.example.com/whatever?u=jason&p=pass%2E%21%21`

Since you're just encoding the entire string, you're ending up with this:

`http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fwhatever%3Fu%3Djason%26p%3Dpass%2E%21%21`

which is not a valid URL. Instead of escaping the entire string, just escape your query part. If your backend server can deal with it, you can build and escape the entire query string because only your server is going to parse that part. If it can't deal with it for any reason, you'll have to escape just the key and value parts of the query string.

Comment: ah I got it. I didn't realize that the whole url isn't supposed to be encoded.  Thank you!  One question - from your answer it would seem I have to encode everything after the ? but you are encoding each argument only, correct?

Comment: So first I encode each argument value and then I create the url with those encoded items? Is that how its supposed to be done?

Comment: @GeekedOut Yes, you could do it that way. You could have a URL that has the base URL without the query string and then encode the query string and append it and use that new URL for your request.